# Duda con un Stored Procedure update

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos update en mi SP el primero funciona bien y me manda un mensaje que el 'update fue hecho' pero me pidieron hacer otro update en un mismo Sp el problema es que me arroja el mensaje del primero que hice, este es el Sp con el cual tengo problemas:

```
IF @Action = 'U1'
    BEGIN
        -- Actualización U1 fbEsActivo
        UPDATE tbr_UsuarioSalon
        SET fbEsActivo = @fbEsActivo
        WHERE fiIdUsuarioSalon = @fiIdUsuarioSalon;
        
        IF @fbEsActivo = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @Mensaje = 'El Usuario ha sido activado';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Mensaje = 'El Usuario ha sido desactivado';
        END

        SET @Registrado = 1;
    END
END;
```

Resumiendo, me aparece el mensaje del primer update y no de los otros.

Ojala puedan apoyarme.

Comment: ¿Y donde está el otro `UPDATE`? Falta contexto.